# GCP: Cross-project PubSub subscription consumption: PERMISSION DENIED

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-iam

Let's say I have two GCP projects: Project A and Project B. Essentially, I need to consume the messages from a subscription set in project A using Project B using Dataflow.

Once I execute my dataflow pipeline I got the error:

```
Warning
2022-07-05T17:30:14.327109904ZQuerying the configuration of Pub/Sub subscription projects/Project-A/subscriptions/my-sub failed. Specific error: PERMISSION_DENIED: 
...
{ argument { string_val: "projects/Project-A/subscriptions/my-sub" key: "subscription_name" } argument { string_val: "User not authorized to perform this action." key: "error" } origin_id: 14668530231585733016 [dist_proc.dax.pubsub_resource_message_ext]: GETTING_PUBSUB_SUBSCRIPTION_FAILED }']
```

I only have a service account from project A. Do you know which permissions I have to set across projects to let Project-B to consume the subscription from project A?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question in a following way:

1/ There is a PubSub topic, and a subscription in a project A

2/ There is a Dataflow (job) - in the project B (another project) - which should stream/read the messages from the project A's subscription.

The questions - what permissions are to be granted?

Here is a documentation - [Security and permissions for pipelines on Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#security_and_permissions_for_pipelines_on)

Pay attention that there are 2 service accounts, and we should take care about the `worker` service account in our context.

In details about access to PubSub - [Accessing Pub/Sub topics and subscriptions](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#accessing_pubsub)

From the best of my knowledge, the roles which are mentioned there, are to be granted to your `worker` service account (from the project B, where the Dataflow job is running) against resources from the project A (subscription, topic or project level, whatever is applicable/required).